# How do I create a POST API method that return JSON?

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-web-api

I am a C# and .Net newbie. I need to get a JSON response instead of a Task. How do I do that?

I have a controller with a POST method like the following:

```
     public Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostDocument() {

              //I have some code here that downloads a multipart file 

        // Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        //String root = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
        var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

        // Read the form data and return an async task.
        var task = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider).
            ContinueWith<HttpResponseMessage>(t =>
            {
                if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
                {
                    Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,   
                                                t.Exception);
                }


                // This illustrates how to get the file names.
                foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName);
                    Console.WriteLine("Server file path: " + file.LocalFileName);

                }

                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);



            });


        return task;

     }
```

Instead of returning `task<>`, I want to return a JSON response like a JSON array or JSON object

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: ok, thank you. Can you tell me the any points about the question?

Comment: I figured out:               returndata = <Some String >      return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,returnData);

Comment: @user3547280 You should create/accept an answer for the fix so others can quickly find the solution.